# Laravel Redirection and logic queue with email verification

Tags: php, laravel

I have one form in frontend where I have there is some city details , rooms details and user registration in one form like I have city name , room name , address etc email addresss and password in same form and I have done 2 logics in one controller for creating cities and registering user 
It is saving the both data in correct table in the database 
but I want that first user should register and if user is vcerified only the room details should be saved in database

I am in confusion wheather to apply if again or what

```
public function checkLogin(Request $request)
{
  $user = User::create([
    'name'=>$request->name,
    'email'=>$request->email,
    'password'=>$request->password,
    'role_id' => config('quickadmin.default_role_id'),
  ]);
  if ($user) {
      if (Auth::check()) {
        $city = TotalCity::create([
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'created_by'=>$request->created_by_id,
        ]);
      }
       return redirect()->to('/admin/home');
  }
}
```

Comment: With `User::create()` you are creating a new user every time you call `checkLogin()`, right? Is this your expected behaviour? Maybe you should check if this user exists first (what if you're trying to save the same email twice)

Comment: Instead of `Auth::check()`, how about `if ($user->email_verified_at)`? However, your logic is a bit off for a `checkLogin()` method

Comment: @senty Yes if email is same it says duplicate email 
my problem is that it is not showing the data in the backend of that particular user who created that

Comment: @senty Tried to answer It is not saving those city data in database and it is neighter redirecting the page to /admin/home after I hit submit

Comment: I fixed the redirect code in the answer, however if `Auth::check()` is failing, that means you don't have authenticated user. Do you want the created user to be logged in at the time of creation? I believe your logic is wrong. I believe you need to use `Auth\RegisterController@registered` to apply this logic entirely

Comment: @senty Yes I want when after register he/she must logged in and goes to /admin/home 

Can you provide me the logic in details please

Comment: I don't know the exact goal you want to achieve, neither the ui so I can't give you the direct code. Read about the out of box register and login

Comment: @senty and it is also not sending the verification mail after I register 
I have to logged in send email again I dont know why ?

Comment: Your User model needs to be `class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail` and `use Notifiable;` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification

Comment: @senty I have already it is sending email while I defaulty register or add user
that is not working in this method

Comment: i am just trying same like when we register user in laravel but from frontend with different form and method

Comment: You can still utilize the `RegisterController`: override `register()` & `registered()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you how I'd probably write this logic:

```
public function checkLogin(Request $request)
{
  $user = User::firstOrCreate([
    'email'=> $request->email,    
  ], 
  [
    'name'=> $request->name,
    'password'=> bcrypt($request->password),
    'role_id' => config('quickadmin.default_role_id'),
  ]);

  if (Auth::check()) {  
  // it's not clear if you utilize `email_verified_at`, if so 
  // if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->email_verified_at) {

    $city = TotalCity::create([
        'name'=>$request->name,
        'created_by'=> Auth::user()->id, // or $user->id depending on your preference
    ]);
  }
  return redirect('/admin/home');
}
```

The `firstOrCreate()` checks if an entry with that email exists, it gets it, otherwise creates it.

---

Furthermore, if I want to check for Authentication, I'd use `'auth'` middleware in my route.

```
Route::get('example', 'ExampleController@checkLogin')->middleware('auth');
```

That removes the need of entire check:

```
if (Auth::check()) { ... }
```